# Entity Framework 6 Code First Relationship/table creation issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to do a Code First migration, but one of the models/tables behave pretty weird when I migrate.

Team and Tournament makes a new Table to reference what team belongs to what tournament and the other way around - That's totally what I want.

I'm trying to do the same with Matchup and Team, defining collections for both, but for some reason it makes a single property, TeamId, in Matchup which is a problem since a Matchup should be able to store more than one Team.

[Screenshots for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trUfX.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more clear in your description. Not much can be made from your problem statement.

Comment: That is how one to many relationships work. The parent id (team id) is stored in the child (matchup) as a foreign key.

Comment: So sorry Lakshmi - I found it very hard to phrase :(

Comment: @SteveGreene But I defined a collection of Matchups in Team and a collection of Teams in Matchup. Shouldn't it be a many-to-many relationship then or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually your configuration looks correct, EF should have created a bidge table behind the scenes called MatchupTeam or TeamMatchup in the database. The TeamID you refer to in Matchup is for the Winner navigation property.

Comment: The problem I see is in Matchup - you have a Team (Winner) and a collection of Teams that EF does not know how to map. Hang on and I will show you. Always paste your code so it is easier to assist.

Comment: Yea - I guess that must be the case.
Thanks a lot Steve - I'll have that in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell EF how to do the relationships when you have multiple references in the same file. I prefer fluent code for this:

Fix models:

```
public class Matchup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int WinnerId { get; set; }  // FK by convention
    public Team Winner { get; set; }
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Matchup> Matchups{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Matchup> MatchupWinners{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments{ get; set; }
}


// Configure 1 to many
modelBuilder.Entity<Matchup>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.Winner)
    .WithMany(p => p.MatchupWinners)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.WinnerId);

// Configure many to many
modelBuilder.Entity<Matchup>()
        .HasMany(s => s.Teams)
        .WithMany(c => c.Matchups)
        .Map(t =>
                {
                    t.MapLeftKey("MatchupId");
                    t.MapRightKey("TeamId");
                    t.ToTable("MatchupTeam");
                });
```

But you can also do it with annotations:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players{ get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Teams")]
    public ICollection<Matchup> Matchups{ get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Winner")]
    public ICollection<Matchup> MatchupWinners{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Got it - The InverseProperty on the Matchups collection and WinnerId in Matchup did the trick.

Thank you a whole lot Steve :)