# One to many relationship with code first. Where this foreign-key came from?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My data class is

```
public class Data
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int LeagueId { get; set; }
        public League League { get; set; }

        public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

        public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

and my team class is

```
public class Team
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Data> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

which generates an extra foreign key `FK_dbo.Data_dbo.Teams_Team_Id` and also and extra column in my `Data` table.

[image]

So my first question is, how that foreign-key was created there?

Can i have two one to many relationships that target at the same table with entity framework?

I need to set both the HomeTeamId and the AwayTeamId in the Data table as one to many relationship

Comment: What is the name of the extra column created in `Data`?

Comment: Are you doing code first?  If so, your migration file should call this out.  Additionally, have you looked at your OnModelCreating method?  Maybe you have something in there?

Comment: btw- by the looks of it, you already have the 1-many relationship on that table to team

Comment: @ClayLong Team_Id

Comment: @Rogala I have nothing at OnModelCreating method

Comment: You need fluent code or annotations so EF can figure out how to match the relationships. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854817/entity-framework-6-code-first-relationship-table-creation-issues/46855464#46855464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LeagueId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeagueId")] /* Add explicit foreign key data annotations */
    public League League { get; set; }

    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeamId")]
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AwayTeamId")]
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        this.HomeTeamData = new HashSet<Data>();
        this.AwayTeamData = new HashSet<Data>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("HomeTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Data> HomeTeamData { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AwayTeam")]
    public virtual ICollection<Data> AwayTeamData { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Actually something like this. It creates HomeTeamId and AwayTeamId but also another two foreign keys Team_Id and Team_Id1

Comment: Post your `OnModelCreating` method, please.

Comment: I have not even overridden the specific method

Comment: @OrElse I think you should be though.  I am assuming you are using .NET Core sense you are not using the ForeignKey attribute.  When you are dealing with FK in .NET Core, you need to focus in on the OnModelCreating method for some of this work.  The .NET Core team is slick, but it's not perfect yet.  ~Cheers

Comment: You can do it without fluent and it has nothing to do with .NET Core. Simply add `[InverseProperty("HomeTeam")]` to HomeTeamData  and  `[InverseProperty("AwayTeam")]` to AwayTeamData so EF can properly match the collection to the corresponding item.

Comment: @Rogala I am using net framework 4.6.1 in a windows forms application. I do not actually understand why this is happening

Comment: You also do not need the ForeignKey annotations since your naming follows the EF convention of Nav Name + Id.

Comment: @OrElse If that's the case, you need to drop that table and use this answer.  It is the correct answer for you.  Only thing is that you do not have to new up the virtuals.  Let LazyLoading handle that for you.

Comment: @SteveGreene edited my answer to reflect your comment

Comment: @SteveGreene The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'HomeTeam' on type 'Data' is not valid. The property 'HomeTeam' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'Team'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property. I guess i need i break sir

Comment: @SteveGreene Just wow. I better start checking that InverseProperty attribute. Thank you sir. It just works now

Comment: Actually I prefer fluent code. Much cleaner classes that way: `modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
        .HasRequired(m => m.HomeTeam)
        .WithMany(p => p.HomeTeamData)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.HomeTeamId);`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be hitting the limit of Entity's ability to figure out what you want.  You may need to consider using some [Entity Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx) to instruct Entity on what you want it to actually do.